# Adding domain as parameter to HTTP basic authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, http-headers

I am writing a REST API with HTTP basic authentication but at some cases username and password is not enough for my server to authenticate the user and I need a domain name as another parameter to authenticate the user.

Why? Because my server authenticates the user against some third party service which may require a username, password and domain as credentials data.

How can I add another parameter to the basic authentication data? Is it allowed?

Comment: surely the domain name forms part of the username?

Comment: so it should look like the following:
username@domain:password 
encoded base64?
so the header will like this?
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWVAZG9tYWluOnBhc3N3b3Jk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the standard HTTP headers do not fit your needs, you can create a custom HTTP header.

However, all the authentication data should be sent in the standard HTTP [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header. From the [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2):

> **4.2.  Authorization**
>
> The `Authorization` header field allows a user agent to authenticate
> itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
> receiving a `401` (Unauthorized) response.  Its value consists of
> credentials containing the authentication information of the user
> agent for the realm of the resource being requested. [...]

Note that the name of this HTTP header is unfortunate because it carries *authentication* information instead of *authorization*.

About the HTTP Basic Authentication scheme, the [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2) defines the following:

> **2. The 'Basic' Authentication Scheme**
>
> The Basic authentication scheme is based on the model that the client
> needs to authenticate itself with a user-id and a password for each
> protection space ("realm"). [...] The server will service the request only if it can validate
> the user-id and password for the protection space applying to the
> requested resource.
>
> [...]
>
> To receive authorization, the client
>
> 1. obtains the user-id and password from the user,
> 2. constructs the user-pass by concatenating the user-id, a single
>    colon (":") character, and the password,
> 3. encodes the user-pass into an octet sequence,
> 4. and obtains the basic-credentials by encoding this octet sequence
>    using [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) into a sequence of [US-ASCII
>    characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20).
>
> [...]
>
> If the user agent wishes to send the user-id "Aladdin" and password
> "open sesame", it would use the following header field:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```
>
> [...]

The [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2) doesn't state anything about using a domain in the Basic Authentication.

But it seems perfectly valid to assume that the `user-id` is composed by the domain name and the user name, using an `@` to separate both, like the following:

```
   user-id = username + @ + domain
```

Comment: The problem is when your username is an email address, difficults parsing